# (Java Swing) How to add image to Button in GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, embedded-resource

I am having trouble loading an image icon of a mouse onto a Jbutton in my program.

I want the image to work when I open the Jar file, so that any computer that uses the program will also be able to see the image.

Note: I am using Netbeans, and have placed the image in my SRC path, as seen here:

[image]

Currently, this is my code for loading the image:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("mouse.png"));
JButton button1 = new JButton();
button1.setIcon(img);
button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
button1.setBounds(x, y, 100, 100);
add(button1);
```

Should I be loading the image via a URL link instead?

Comment: What trouble are you having?  Is the image file on the classpath so the getResource method can find it?

Comment: Hi Norm, I am having trouble loading the image onto my JButton. As I stated in my question, I have added the image in my Source Packages file, but im not sure how to put it onto my JButton.

Comment: 1) *"Should I be loading the image via a URL link instead?"* `getResource` returns a link! 2) You're obviously inexperienced with using this method of loading resources, as to tell if that would work, we need to know if the image is stored in the same package as the code loading it. That's the only thing that would work, given the snippet above. 3) General tips: prefix the path with `/` to indicate to locate the image form the 'base' of the class path, then use the path from there, to the image.

Comment: If the code posted is in the same package as `mouse.png` (and is not static)  it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Make a image folder in Source Packages**

[image: Follow this Image]

**upload photos under the image folder**

**Java Code for add image icon**

```
jButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Image/icons8_Add_30px.png"))); // NOI18N
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Received this error: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)

Comment: If you need only set icon in Button then just use- 

jButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Image/icons.png")));

this is the code for add icon in button

Comment: I edited the code snippet down to the only relevant line, but note that `image` as seen in the screenshot and `Image` as seen in the code would mean it fails. `getResource` is case sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

When you refer image, pay attention to its location in the class path. In your case the reference should look like `getResource("com/mycompany/.../mouse.png")`.

Comment: `"com..` should best be `"/com..`. See my comment for details.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: "best"? It is arguable. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html: *Absolute names are stripped of their starting "/" and are passed...*.